# When to choose population over references to parents in Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I understand storing ref arrays on parents quickly becomes inefficient with large arrays:

```
{ 
  _id = ObjectId("58adsa4314ds43dd5sa14113aa"),
  name: "Starbuck",
  children: [
    ObjectId("58a8a8f2a87fcb135f09d6aa"),
    ObjectId("58a8a8f2a87fcb135f09d6ab"),
    (...1000x)
  ]
}
```

vs

```
{ 
  name: "Child of Starbuck 1",
  parent: ObjectId("58adsa4314ds43dd5sa14113aa"),
}
{ 
  name: "Child of Starbuck 2",
  parent: ObjectId("58adsa4314ds43dd5sa14113aa"),
}
```

But in a scenario where you have max 20 references to child documents, it seems like sacrificing the ease of use of mongoose Population is a big trade-off for a negligible performance gain (which itself is debatable, since you can retrieve all child documents in one call with Population)

What are the pros and cons of either and when should either be used?